# How does the gradient descent work when the one hot encoded labels are all zeros?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network, cross-entropy

I've got a dataset of images of the vineyard taken from above I'd like to sub-classify, there are 3 big classes [ground,vegetal,vineyard] and some of them are divided into several subclasses : vegetal:[grass,flower], vineyard:[healthy, disease A, disease B]. I'd like to design a neural network with three outputs, the problem is that for some class or subclass (e.g. grass) some outputs might be irrelevant (e.g. the disease output). This is not a problem for inference but in order to train my model, I'd like to find the right (multi-)labels so that, for instance, when computing the error on a grass sample, I don't want the weights which are responsible only for the disease ouput to be updated.

The idea I had is to give for each class 3 one hot vectors which will be zero if the classification output is irrelevant, for instance a healthy vineyard sample will be encoded as [[0,0,1],[0,0],[1,0,0]] and a ground sample [[1,0,0],[0,0],[0,0,0]]. I thought this would work because, when computing the error's gradient of the disease/vegetal output for a ground sample, it should be zero.

[mathematical explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N7ot.png)

However, it looks like that the  gradient of the error computed with "zeros one hot labels" (sorry for the name...) is actually non zero.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
input_layer=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,128,3))
x=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,kernel_size=(2,2),activation='relu')(input_layer)
x=tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,kernel_size=(2,2),activation='relu')(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),activation='relu')(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),activation='relu')(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),activation='relu')(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
output=tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax')(x)
model=tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs=output)
model.compile('sgd','binary_crossentropy')

X=np.random.randint(0,255,(1,128,128,3))
Y=np.zeros((1,3))

old_weights=model.layers[-1].get_weights()
model.train_on_batch(X,Y)
new_weights=model.layers[-1].get_weights()

print old_weights[0]-new_weights[0]
```

gives me a non zero tensor, can anyone explain me what is happening here?